# Upgrade Groovy installation on slave node to a recent version

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm refactoring/enhancing an **Execute Groovy Script** build step and am hitting a version compatibility issue between my dev/debugging environment, which is running Groovy 2.3.7, and the version deployed by the groovy-plugin autoinstaller to the slave. We have that set to the relatively stale 2.0.6. The upshot is that I can't use this very handy 2.3+ AST annotation on the Jenkins slave:

```
file:/C:/Jenkins/workspace/Foo/bar/com/ns1/ns2/MyClass.groovy: 13: unable to resolve class groovy.transform.Sortable
 @ line 13, column 1.
   import groovy.transform.Sortable
   ^

1 error
```

What is the path of least resistance to upgrade the slave's Groovy to 2.3.7 or higher? Of note is the autoinstaller only goes up to 2.2.1. (If that's even a viable option here.)

[image: Groovy plugin autoinstaller limited to 2.2.1 max.]

Our Jenkins Groovy plugin is at the latest version, 1.24, and the Jenkins master is at 1.580.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that was simpler than expected. You can simply kill the http://groovy.codehaus.org installer and point to a fresher repo URL directly by adding a new like so:

[image: Replacing default autoinstaller with a pinned repo URL]

Upon job execution the autoinstaller will delete the old Groovy install and unpack the new one. I'm pretty sure it will check timestamps/hashes/something so as not to override the install with the same version on the next run.